# Objective C- numberOfRowsInSection method is not called properly in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In my table view, I have 7 section. Each section count is 3 initially.
When I launch my app, numberOfRowsInSection method is calling from last section count(6) but data are displayed in all sections properly.
When I reload my table after insert event numberOfRowsInSection is calling again from 6 not from 0 so how to resolve it?

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   NSMutableArray *arrayOfItems = [workScheduleArray objectAtIndex:section];
   return arrayOfItems.count;
}
-(void)insertNewDutyTimeRow:(UIButton *)addNewRowBtn atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)addNewDutyIndex
{
  insertNewRow = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  [insertNewRow addObject:@"Start Time"];
  [insertNewRow addObject:@"End time"];
  [insertNewRow addObject:@"Service type"];

  newArray = [workScheduleArray objectAtIndex:addNewDutyIndex.section];
  [newArray insertObject:insertNewRow atIndex:addNewDutyIndex.row+1];
  NSLog(@"WorkSchedule array:%@",workScheduleArray[addNewDutyIndex.section]);

 [self.personalTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: You don't provide sufficient information as to your tableView object.

Comment: Sorry EI Tomato numberOfRowsInSection is called from last section count (6).

Comment: You still don't.

Comment: Show the cellForRowAt delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Your numberOfRowsInSection is generic, it returns the same number for all your sections. it begins by section 0 and ends by your last section (in your case its 6). So this is why you must specify all the cases. For example you can do this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     switch (section) {
         case 0:         
              NSMutableArray *arrayOfItems = [workScheduleArray objectAtIndex:section];
              return arrayOfItems.count;

         {...}

     }
}
```

Comment: @Mohamed i tried your code. section 0 only called at 4 times remaining sections were called only 1 time. Why section 0 is called 4 times?

Comment: Yes its normal, UITableView can calls numberOfRowsInSection multiple times (even for the same section). The tableview internally needs to know how many rows it has. It is called 4 times because Apple's tableview code needs to know, at 4 different times, how many rows are in your one section. Apple makes no guarantees how often UIKit may call one of your delegate methods.